# How does this select in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

How does this select in MongoDB

```
select cidade 
from rendaxeducação 
where idheducacao = (
    select max(idheducacao) 
    from rendaxeducacao 
    where idh=2000
);
```

Comment: Have you tried something yet ?

Comment: Sub queries in this manner are currently impossible within MongoDB itself, you would need to do two queries, one for the MAX result and one for selecting based upon the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 db.rendaxeducacao.aggregate([
        {$math : {idh : 2000}                  //  fiter only where idh=2000
        },
        {$group: { _id: 1, 
                   max_idheducacao : {$max : $idheducacao}  // find max
          }
        },
        {$project:{                          //  select cidade 
               _id:0,
               cidade:1
          }  
        } 

  ])
```

rendaxeducacao = collection