# How would this query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

example document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5338796453370917f05bb064"),
    "Sigla" : "CE",
    "Regiao" : "Nordeste",
    "Codigo" : 2306009,
    "Municipio" : "Iracema",
    "1991" : 52.40499877929688,
    "2000" : 108.7089996337891,
    "IDHEducacao" : {
        "1991" : 0.516,
        "2000" : 0.735
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5338796453370917f05bb065"),
    "Sigla" : "CE",
    "Regiao" : "Nordeste",
    "Codigo" : 2306108,
    "Municipio" : "Irauçuba",
    "1991" : 47.72299957275391,
    "2000" : 62.65800094604492,
    "IDHEducacao" : {
        "1991" : 0.491,
        "2000" : 0.692
    }
}
```

---> Mongodb

I made the following query

```
{"$group":
    {
        "_id":{"Regiao":"$Regiao"},
                "IDHEducao_max_2000" : {"$max" : "$2000"},      
    }
}
```

I want to show the region, the largest index of the field in 2000, and what is the municipality that owns this index. But I'm not getting

Comment: MAX(2000) !!! What is it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does this select in MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22922517/how-does-this-select-in-mongodb)

Comment: You really need to understand how this site works. Do not post a duplicate question just because you other question was shut down. Edit that instead.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like `2000` is the name of one of the fields in your document, which I find strange.

The SQL below:

```
SELECT Regiao, MAX( 2000 ) AS Indice FROM table1 GROUP BY Regiao
```

can be written in MongoDB as

```js
db.table1.aggregate([
    {"$group": {
        "_id":{"Regiao":"$Regiao"},
        "IDHEducao_max_2000" : {"$max" : "$2000"}}
    },
    {"$project": {"_id":0, "Regiao":"$_id", "Indice":"$IDHEducao_max_2000"}}
]}
```

But this SQL:

```js
SELECT Sigla, Regiao, Municipio, MAX( 2000 ) AS Indice FROM table1 GROUP BY Regiao
```

is **NOT** valid.  When you use GROUP BY, you can only select fields used in the GROUP BY or aggregated values of other fields (i.e., SUM(), COUNT(), etc..).  However, if all you need is some value for the other fields, you could use the `$first` or `$last` operators.  Note that these operators are usually used only after a sort phase to get min/max:

```js
db.table1.aggregate([
    {"$group": {
        "_id":{"Regiao":"$Regiao"},
        "Sigla" : {"$first" : "$Sigla"}}
        "Municipio" : {"$first" : "$Municipio"}}
        "IDHEducao_max_2000" : {"$max" : "$2000"}}
    },
    {"$project": {"_id":0, "Sigla":1, "Regiao":"$_id", "Municipio":1,
                  "Indice":"$IDHEducao_max_2000"}}
]}
```

**EDIT:** OP was updated with the question below:

> I want to show the region, the largest index of the field in 2000, and what is the municipality that owns this index.

If you use the `$sort` phase of the aggregation pipeline followed by `$group` phase and make use of the [`$first`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator, you can get the results you want:

```js
db.table1.aggregate([
    // Sort by (City ASC, Index DESC)
    {$sort:{"Regiao":1, "2000":-1}}, 
    // Group by City and get the max Index and corresponding Municipality
    {$group:{
        _id:"$Regiao", 
        Index:{$first:"$2000"}, 
        Municipio:{$first:"$Municipio"}}
    }
])
```

Comment: Somehow thinking that this is not even close to the actual result required. You needed to actually ask a question in a comment instead.

Comment: Anand Jayabalan, but is there any way to show the city that has the highest rate?

Comment: i don't see `city` or `rate` anywhere in the document???  can you edit your original question to include a sample document and clearly stating what exactly you are trying to query?

Comment: Anand Jayabalan. Edited the question

Comment: @user3508412, based on my understand of your question, I've added another query to my post.  See if that helps.

Comment: Anand Jayabalan, você saberia como é esse select no mongodb, eu usei o Mysql. select T.* from IDHeducaco T where T.2000 = (select max(TT.2000) from IDHEducacao TT where T.Regiao = TT.Regiao group by TT.Regiao)